# Matching a Source image to a destination image in python

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Okay guys, I am stuck trying to create a histogram matching for two images; a template image and a destination image(destination meaning the image where i want to match the template image). Rather than displaying the matched image, i get a blank image. I feel like i am exhausted at this hence why i came to SO. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Any Help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
def matching(template, target, numberOfBins=256):

    templateHist, bins1 = np.histogram(template.flatten(), numberOfBins, density = False)
    targetHist, bins2 = np.histogram(target.flatten(), numberOfBins, density = False)
    cdfTemplate = templateHist.cumsum() #Cumulative distributed function
    cdfTemplate = (255 * cdfTemplate / cdfTemplate[-1]) #normalize
    cdfTarget = targetHist.cumsum()
    cdfTarget = (255 * cdfTarget / cdfTarget[-1]).astype(np.float64)
    im2 = np.interp(template.flatten(), cdfTemplate, bins1[:-1])
    im3 = np.interp(im2, cdfTarget, bins2[:-1])
    result = im3.reshape((template.shape))

    return result
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32655686/1461210

Comment: it means that cdfTemplate[-1] is returning 0.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `cdfTemplate[-1]` is equal to 0, which results in all of the elements in `cdfTemplate` becoming NaNs. This implies that the sum of `templateHist` must also be 0. It's harder to explain why this should be the case, given that it consists of histogram bin counts, and the automatic selection of histogram bin edges ought to ensure that at least one bin contains a non-zero count. What are `template` and `target` like? I'm guessing that they are masked arrays?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would give you all-zero bin counts is if you were passing an empty array to `np.histogram`

Comment: It is passing in an empty array into np.histogram. Every article i read up on histogram matching gives me similiar functionality and design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The error message is telling you that `cdfTemplate[-1]` is equal to zero, which results in all of the elements in `cdfTemplate` becoming NaNs.
- Working backwards, this implies that the sum of `templateHist` must also be zero.
- `templateHist` contains bin counts computed from `template.flatten()`. Since you haven't specified a set of weights for `np.histogram`, there's no way that any of the elements in `templateHist` could be negative. Therefore `templateHist` must be all zeros.
- You are also passing a positive integer as the `bins` parameter to `np.histogram`, and you haven't specified the `range` parameter. Therefore if `template` contains *any* values then `np.histogram` should automatically select a set of bin edges such that at least one of the counts would be positive.
- If `template` contained NaNs or infinite values you should get a `ValueError` rather than a vector of all-zero bin counts.
- Therefore the logical conclusion is that `template` must be an empty array.

Comment: I'm a little lost when you said i havent specified the range parameter. Can you be a little more clear.

Comment: [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) accepts a `range` parameter that can be used to specify the `(lower, upper)` limits for the range of bin edges. In principle you could have got all-zero bin counts because you passed two numbers such that all of the values in `template` fell outside this range, but you didn't.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm debugging my code and found out as soon as the first second statement in my *hist function*  gets executed, the result == 0.

Comment: Okay, @ali_m, Can you guide me in selecting my range. I tried following [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html] but it still is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111951/discussion-between-brandon-j-and-ali-m).

Comment: Added what the contents were.

Comment: That can't be correct - if you pass an array containing NaNs to `np.histogram` you should get a `ValueError`. What is `type(template)`?

Comment: It's a 2000 x 2000 array.

Comment: What kind of array? A `numpy.ndarray`? A masked array?

Comment: it's a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're describing using numpy 1.10.4. The array you've shown in your question contains at least one NaN. If I pass an array containing any NaNs to `np.histogram` I get a `ValueError: range parameter must be finite`, not a vector of all-zero bin counts. That said, I strongly suspect that the fact that `template` contains NaNs is the cause of your problems.

Comment: Okay thanks anyways. I'll accept that answer. I'll figure it out.