# OpenCV - Balance brightness of two images (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm new in OpenCV and also in Image processing.

I have two images in grayscale. I want to balance their brightness (both images should have very similar brightness).

I think about `equalizeHist`, but the result doesn't depend on the second image. I also find information about histogram matching, but I don't find any working example in OpenCV.

Could you give me a hint and example how to do that?

Comment: If histogram matching is what you are looking for, have a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655686/histogram-matching-of-two-images-in-python-2-x) and [THIS](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19980/histogram-matching-specification-in-python). Although the implementation is in python it would be of much help.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't look only for histogram matching. Just for some method for balancing brightness.

Comment: It would help if you convert your images to LAB color space and then apply histogram matching on the `L` channel before converting the images to RGB