# image transformation by color

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have two RGB images. size of first image is 256x256x3 and size of second image is 1024x1024x3. Both images are the same, but different resolutions and Slightly different colors. I want the second picture to have the first picture colors while the resolution does not change. How can I do this in opencv?

first image (lower resolution):
https://photos.app.goo.gl/psgXoCdbFeh1Jv5PA/
second image (higher resolution): https://photos.app.goo.gl/yCgd4iRPvSwXEjLg7/

Comment: Are you using python? Please add the images in you question.

Comment: yes python. below are links of photo.

Comment: what you are looking for is something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655686/histogram-matching-of-two-images-in-python-2-x) or in matlab [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhistmatch.html) (this one has more examples of how it works)