# How to map predicted values distribution to trianning data distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Like the figure below, the distribution of the predicted values is different from ground truth - `y_test`.
Can I fit the distribution of the predicted values to the distribution of all data?
Here are some pseudo data.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
y_test = np.random.gamma(2, 2, 1000)
y_predict = np.random.normal(2, 2, 1000)
sns.distplot(y_test)
sns.distplot(y_predict)
```

[image]

Comment: You could use histogram matching, typically it is used for images, but it works for 1d distributions as well, see foe example this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655686/histogram-matching-of-two-images-in-python-2-x

Comment: @AnvarKurmukov Great! That is what I want.