# Equivalent C++ Implementation for scikit-image match_histograms

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want to perform histogram matching on OpenCV `Mat` images in C++.

I know in python I can use [skimage.exposure.match_histograms](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.match_histograms) method.

Is there any equivalent implementation of this method in C++?

Comment: FYI: The source code of skimage is on github: [scikit-image/scikit-image](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/98e157969bafabdff8b262ef2328f02c797ac8d3/skimage/exposure/histogram_matching.py).

Comment: I found this [C++ implementation](https://github.com/samiranrl/Scilab-Toolbox/blob/master/sci_gateway/cpp/opencv_imhistmatch.cpp).

Comment: @Rotem I tried to use your suggested implementation but it runs slowly (a couple of  seconds for a 960x600 image) and output is 90 degree rotated.

Comment: You may have to reimplement it... I found a Python implementation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655686/histogram-matching-of-two-images-in-python-2-x). You may have to find a C implementation of `interp`.