# How to create an image with intensities 0 to 255 with normal distribution?

Tags: python, image-processing, normal-distribution

To solve my last question [How to do histogram matching with normal distribution as reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75884220/how-to-do-histogram-matching-with-normal-distribution-as-reference?noredirect=1#comment133860591_75884220) I want to create an image with normal distribution. For that for every pixel of the new image I want to choose a number from 0 to 255 randomly and with normal distribution. I've done this:

```
normal_image = np.random.normal(0, 1, size = (M,N))
```

But the dtype of this image is float64. So then I did this:

```
normal_image = np.random.normal(0, 1, size = (M,N)).astype('uint8')
```

But I'm not sure if this is a correct approach. Should I choose random numbers from the integers 0 to 255 based on normal distribution?(Which I don't know how to do this!)

Would you please guide me?

Comment: See the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411633/how-to-generate-a-random-normal-distribution-of-integers

Comment: You don’t need to make this image, if all you will do to it is compute its histogram. Just create a histogram with the bins filled according to your target distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize values from `normal` between 0 and 1 then multiply by 255:

```
import numpy as np

M = 10
N = 10
n = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(M, N))
s = (n - n.min()) / (n.max() - n.min())
i = (255 * s).astype(np.uint8)
```

Output:

```
>>> i
array([[146, 117, 141, 120,  64, 105, 155, 154,  89,  81],
       [109,  86, 152, 105, 168,  51, 195,  50, 117,  65],
       [112,   0,  95, 102,  82,  74,  79,  98,  27, 183],
       [131, 172, 102, 220, 255,  94,  96, 138, 111, 106],
       [131, 170, 151,  97, 169, 138,  28,  74, 125, 151],
       [119, 170,  83, 190,  65, 184,  40, 183, 121, 104],
       [191, 193,  91,  80, 145,  49,  92,  87, 160, 132],
       [141,  76, 131,  65,  93,  98, 187,  66,  98, 168],
       [185,  81, 182, 210,  90, 151,  39,  99, 104, 123],
       [ 98, 109, 154, 215, 130,  93, 146, 156, 121,  37]], dtype=uint8)
```

For this array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(i.ravel(), bins=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this new distribution doesn't have the mean 0 and the sd 1. Right?

Comment: How do you want to have the mean is 0 with numbers between 0 and 255? Except if all numbers are 0