# Ajustment of brightness and contrast of slices of a volume

Tags: python, image

I happen to have a volume of many slices which are 16bit. Each slice has a different contrast and brightness, and needs to be converted to 8 bits while having the smae B&C and not losing information in the process. My current approach consist in:

1 - Normalizing the pixel values to match the 8 bit distribution (with the following function):

```
def normalize_volume(slice_data,):
    _min, _max = np.min(slice_data), np.max(slice_data)
    slice_data = (slice_data - _min) / (_max - _min)
    slice_data = (slice_data * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return slice_data
```

2 - Trasnlate the mode (peak of my histogram, in my case the background) to a given point in the 8bit range to control brightness:

```
def peak_histogram(slice_data, target_value):
    histogram, bins = np.histogram(slice_data.flatten(), bins=256)
    peak = bins[histogram.argmax()]
    return (slice_data + (target_value - peak)).astype(np.uint8)
```

3 - Adjust the standard deviation of the slice to match a certain value of standard deviation thus controlling the contrast in the image:

```
def remove_std(slice_data):
    std = np.std(slice_data)
    mean = np.mean(slice_data)
    res = (slice_data - mean) * (25 / std) + mean
    return res.astype(np.uint8)
```

Finally I again normalize the slices because returning just `astype(np.uint8)` truncates the values thuis losing information (some values of the histogram are gaps with 0 counts).

This is the code I use to perform this:

```
for idx in tqdm.tqdm(range(volume.shape[0]), total=volume.shape[0]):
    slice_data = normalize_volume(volume[idx])    
    slice_data = remove_std(slice_data)
    slice_data = peak_histogram(slice_data, 128)
    slice_data = normalize_volume(slice_data)
    # v8[idx] = slice_data
    tifffile.imwrite(f"./v8/v8_{idx}.tif", slice_data, compression="zlib")
```

The problem is in the end there are slight changes in mode and td dev that are significant for the final analysis I need to perform, like 1 or 2 points. How can I improve my approach??

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I have found it quite helpful for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047048/7750891

Comment: My problem with such approach is that the distribution changes over the volume, where there is a second peak which varies over the slices, incresing with the number of slices, while in this approach all histograms of my slices are the same over the